# Aiogram кастомные фильтры

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

Пытаюсь добавить фильтр для проверки, есть ли пользователь в списке администраторов, но он срабатывает несколько раз.
Если боту отправить /test, то он начнет флудить сообщением "Только для администраторов", попробовал выводить список айдишек в check(), выводит тоже несколько раз. Как исправить?
И при чем фильтр срабатывает не только на команду /test, но и на любое сообщение. При получении ботом любого сообщения он начинает флудить точно так же, как и при получении команды /test

Знаю, что для BoundFilter нужен init, но с ним бот кидает еще больше сообщений

Структура:

bot/

|--bot.py

|--filters/

......|--admin_filter.py

......|--**init**.py

|--handlers/

......|--handler1.py

......|--**init**.py

Содержимое bot.py:

```py
import filters, handlers
from aiogram import executor
from loader import dp
from utils.notify_admins import on_startup_notify
from utils.set_bot_commands import set_default_commands   
 
async def on_startup(dispatcher):
    await set_default_commands(dispatcher)
    await on_startup_notify(dispatcher)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup, skip_updates=True)
```

Содержимое /filters/admin_filter.py:

```py
from data.config import load_admins
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import BoundFilter
from aiogram.types.message import Message
 
 
class IsAdmin(BoundFilter):
    async def check(self, msg: Message):
        print('check')
        ADMINS = await load_admins()
        # ADMINS = список айдишек администраторов
 
        user = msg.from_user.id
        if user not in ADMINS:
            await msg.answer('Только для администраторов')
        return user in ADMINS
```

Содержимое /filters/**init**.py:

```py
from loader import dp
from .admin_filter import IsAdmin
 
 
if __name__ == "filters":
    dp.filters_factory.bind(IsAdmin)
```

Содержимое /handlers/handler1.py:

```py
from filters.admin_filter import IsAdmin
from aiogram.types.message import Message
 
from loader import dp
 
 
@dp.message_handler(IsAdmin(), commands='test')
async def show_apanel(msg: Message):
    await msg.answer(msg)
```

Содержимое /handlers/**init**.py:

```py
from . import handler1
```

Answer (score 0):

Классу фильтра должна быть присвоена переменная key:

```
...
    class IsAdmin(BoundFilter):
        key = "is_admin"

        def __init__(self, admin):
           self.admin = admin

        async def check(self, msg: Message):
...
```

Фильтр должен быть зарегистрирован перед запуском (и применением). Использование следующее:

```
@dp.message_handler(is_admin=True, commands='test')
async def show_apanel(msg: Message):
```